# Proving equality of integrals by Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Claim: $\int_0^t\int_0^y\sigma(v,y)\sigma^*(v,y)dvdy=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t(\sigma^*(v,t))^2dv$, where $\sigma^*(v,t)\equiv\int_0^t\sigma(v,y)dy$, and $\sigma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a real-valued function that is suitably nice that we can apply Fubini's theorem.

Attempt: Applying Fubini's theorem, we obtain $\int_0^t\int_0^y\sigma(v,y)\sigma^*(v,y)dvdy=\int_0^t\int_v^t\sigma(v,y)\sigma^*(v,y)dydv$.

I'm not seeing how to simplify it further. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you suspect that equality holds?